# Pytorch loss does't change in vgg 19 model

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, vgg-net, imagenet

In pytorch I made a model vgg19 for classification tiny imagenet:

```
model = nn.Sequential(
    nn.BatchNorm2d(3),
    nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=64, kernel_size=(3,3), padding=1),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=64, kernel_size=(3,3), padding=1),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.MaxPool2d((2,2)),
    nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=(3,3), padding=1),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=128, kernel_size=(3,3), padding=1),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.MaxPool2d((2,2)),
    nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding=1),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding=1),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding=1),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding=1),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.MaxPool2d((2,2)),
    nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding=1),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding=1),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding=1),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding=1),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.MaxPool2d((2,2)),
    nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding=1),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding=1),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding=1),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding=1),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.MaxPool2d((2,2)),
    nn.Flatten(),
    nn.Linear(25088, 4096),
    nn.Linear(4096, 1000),
    nn.Linear(1000, 200),
    nn.Softmax(),
    nn.Dropout2d(),
)
```

In the learning process, the loss remains at approximately the same value (5.3 +- 0.01).

```
###############
iter = 4000 / 80000
loss = 5.295811176300049
###############
iter = 4800 / 80000
loss = 5.298299789428711
###############
iter = 5600 / 80000
loss = 5.309792995452881
###############
iter = 6400 / 80000
loss = 5.3179707527160645
###############
iter = 7200 / 80000
loss = 5.3179707527160645
```

I have already tried to increase and decrease lr, batch_size. But still no idea how to fix it.

Training code
**(epochs = 10, loss = cross_entropy, optim = Adam(lr = 0.01), X_batch.shape = (batch_size, 3, 224, 224)**:

```
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    i = 0
    for (X_batch, y_batch) in train_batch_gen:
        X_batch = Variable(torch.FloatTensor(X_batch)).cuda()
        y_batch = Variable(torch.LongTensor(y_batch)).cuda()
        logits = model.cuda().forward(X_batch)
        opt.zero_grad()
        loss = lossFunc(logits, y_batch)
        loss.backward()
        opt.step()

        train_loss.append(loss.data.cpu().numpy())
        if i % (batch_size*100) == 0:
            print("###############")
            print(f"iter = {i} / {80000}")
            print(f"loss = {np.mean(train_loss[-len(train_dataset) // batch_size :])}")
        i += batch_size
```

Comment: Which loss function are you using?

Comment: i used cross entropy loss

Answer (score 2):

[`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) applies log-softmax, but you also apply softmax in the model:

```py
nn.Linear(1000, 200),
nn.Softmax(),
nn.Dropout2d(),
```

The output of your model must be the raw logits, without the `nn.Softmax()`.

Additionally, dropout should not be used just before the output of the model, since that effectively wipes out some of the classes, making the loss punish something that would have been correct otherwise. Dropout should only be used between layers as a regularisation.

Comment: i delete nn.SoftMax and nn.Dropout lines, but loss same doesn't changed. 5.3 +- 0.01

Comment: The only other possibly problematic part of the model would be the `nn.BatchNorm2d(3)` at the beginning. Otherwise, it's probably something related to your data or training procedure.

Comment: removing the batch normalization  also does not give the desired effect, apparently the problem is in the learning process

Comment: I added a code for training, could you please take a look?

Comment: Make sure the images are represented as floats in range [0, 1] (not [0, 255]). Let it train for a while (several epochs), and look at the loss per epoch, not within the epoch, because if it hasn't seen a certain class before, it cannot predict it, so it's always going to be wrong in the first epoch. And possibly reduce the learning rate.

Comment: I don't know why, but my image represented as floats in range ~[-2.2, 2.2]